# ResultSet not returned

Tags: java, sqlite

I am getting "Query does not return ResultSet" even after using executeUpdate() am facing the same issue.I used SQlite.i have added my code here

```
try{
        String str = userid.getText();
        char[] str1 = userpass.getPassword();
        String str2 = Arrays.toString(str1);
        Connection con;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Ajay/AppData/Local/Temp/Rar$EXa0.794/SQLiteStudio/Login");
        Statement stmt;
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        String strng = "insert into login(user,password) values('"+str+"','"+str2+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(strng);
        con.commit();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e);
    }
```

Comment: hey is this the code that you used? Your code has executeQuery() but your tagline says you used executeUpdate(). I was just curious

Comment: And `stmt.executeUpdate(-);` for insert query.

Comment: Call `connection.commit();` after `executeUpdate(-);`.

Comment: Still the same issue :(

Comment: i have updated my code but still am getting the same exception